# How to choose which version of Visual Studio gets pulled up by default?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have VS 2012 and 2013 installed on my system.

I have a 2012 project that I want to get pulled up in VS 2013 when I double-click it from the Windows Explorer.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want specific slns to open in 2013, you can open the sln file in a text editor, and change the line

```
# Visual Studio 2012
```

to

```
# Visual Studio 2013
```

Note that it will ask you to upgrade the projects to 2013 when you open it for the first time. If you want all of 2013's compiler features you will have to upgrade, but if you chose not to it will still load in the 2013 IDE and you get some of the IDE related features.

Answer (score 0):

Right click any solution file and select `Open with...` option. Use `Visual Studio Version Selector` as the default program to use for Visual Studio solution files.
[image]

Comment: Using this method would still cause VS2012 to be used for VS2012 solutions, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: When I try this method, it just opens it in VS 2012.